# DLL Memory leaks in the heap

Tags: c#, c++, opencv, dll

I am debugging someone's code and I get an error: This may be due to a corruption of the heap, which indicates a bug in .exe or any of the DLLs it has loaded. I researched and have come to understand that this is due to some memory leaks, objects not being deleted properly from the heap. I looked and looked at the code (Debug line by line) and it crashes at the return statement. Here is the code: Where could the problem be?

Firstly the c# code that calls the DLL

```
    public class Analysis
    {
        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, Pack = 1), Serializable]
        public struct Pothole
        {
            public int Id;
            public int FrameNumber;
            public int LeftX;
            public int TopY;
            public int Width;
            public int Height;
            public int Certainty; // note that this is a percentage value, hence integer
            public double Latitude;
            public double Longitude;
            public double Speed;
            public double Area;
            public double Volume;
            [MarshalAsAttribute(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 20)]
            public string TimeCreated;
            [MarshalAsAttribute(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 200)]
            public string CroppedImage;
            [MarshalAsAttribute(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 200)]
            public string LeftImage;
            [MarshalAsAttribute(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 200)]
            public string RightImage;
        };

        private int progress;
        public int Progress
        {
            get { return progress; }
            set { progress = value; }
        }

        public List<FileInfo> AllVideoFiles;
        public List<FileInfo> FramesInDir;
        public List<GpsPoint> GpsList;
        public VideoMetaData MetaData;
        public List<TrackPothole> PotholeList;
        public VideoHandling VideoHandler;

        public int verbose; //if verbose, then you get a lot of wordy output on what the program is doing

        private VspDatabaseEntities1 _vde;        

        [UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.StdCall)]
        public delegate void ProgressCallback(int value);
        public event ProgressCallback OnProgressUpdated;

        //initializes video files and calibraiton file names
        [DllImport(@"Analyser.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
        public static extern int Initialize(string SettingsDir, int SettingDirLength, string LeftVideoFile, int LeftFileLength, 
            string RightVideoFile, int RightFileLength, string GpsCoordsFile, int GpsFileLength, string OutputDirectory, int OutputDirLength);

        //analyse road files (do everything)
        [DllImport(@"Analyser.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
        public static extern int Start([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.FunctionPtr)] ProgressCallback callbackPointer, int verbose);

        //Does the analysis of videos, uses the c++ analysis Start() function
        public void Go(ProgressBar bar)
        {
            //flag -> should actually be set outside of function, can't find the outside
            verbose = 1;            

            //obtain parameters from settings.settings
            string inputDir = Properties.Settings.Default["InputDir"].ToString();
            string outputDir = Properties.Settings.Default["OutputDir"].ToString();
            string settingsDir = Properties.Settings.Default["SettingsDir"].ToString();

            //setup directories and filenames            
            //string camfile = settingsDir + "\\" + "Calib.yaml"; => now we send the directory, not the specific file
            string rightvid = "";
            string leftvid = "";
            string gpsfile = "";

            //Associate multiple files according to creation times and loop through matching pairs 
            //(this works because of the copy operation? -> but won't everything have the same time then?)
            AllVideoFiles = GetFiles(inputDir, "*.avi");            
            List<FileInfo> rightvids = new List<FileInfo>(AllVideoFiles.Where(v => v.FullName.Contains("3D_R")).OrderBy(v => v.CreationTime));
            List<FileInfo> leftvids = new List<FileInfo>(AllVideoFiles.Where(v => v.FullName.Contains("3D_L")).OrderBy(v => v.CreationTime));
            List<FileInfo> gpsfiles = new List<FileInfo>(GetFiles(inputDir, "*.txt").OrderBy(g => g.CreationTime));
            Console.WriteLine("Got this far1");
            //Check that the number of right and left video files and gps files match
            int lowestCount = 0;
            if (rightvids.Count != leftvids.Count)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error: The number of right camera videos does not match the number of left camera videos!");
                if (rightvids.Count < leftvids.Count)
                    lowestCount = rightvids.Count;
                else
                    lowestCount = leftvids.Count;
            }
            else
                lowestCount = rightvids.Count;

            if (gpsfiles.Count != lowestCount)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error: The number of gps data files does not match the number of right camera video files!");
                if (gpsfiles.Count < lowestCount)
                    lowestCount = gpsfiles.Count;
            }

            //@todo 
            //Currently, looping through the files and hoping there is only one in the file.
            Console.WriteLine("Got this far2");
            for (int i = 0; i < lowestCount; i++)
            {
                rightvid = rightvids[i].FullName;
                leftvid = leftvids[i].FullName;
                gpsfile = gpsfiles[i].FullName;

                if (verbose==1)
                    Console.WriteLine("C# FileNames: " + settingsDir + " " + outputDir + " " + leftvid + " " + gpsfile);

                //Pass the filenames to the c++ functions
                int InitReturn = Initialize(settingsDir, settingsDir.Length, leftvid, leftvid.Length,
                    rightvid, rightvid.Length, gpsfile, gpsfile.Length, outputDir, outputDir.Length);

                if (verbose == 1)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Initilize return value : " + InitReturn);
                    Report();
                }

                //Setup the progress bar
                ProgressCallback callback = (value) => bar.Dispatcher.Invoke(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Normal,
                    new Action(delegate() {bar.Value = value;} ));

                //***RUN THE ANALYSIS
                Console.WriteLine("Got this far4");
                int start_ret_val = Start(callback, verbose);
                if (verbose==1) Console.WriteLine("Start return value: " + start_ret_val);

                //Create the pothole array
                Pothole[] potArr = new Pothole[10000];
                Thread.Sleep(1000); //@todo Why sleep?

                if (start_ret_val > 0)
                {
                    //fill up the array 
                    ///@todo How does this impact the memory wastage?
                    potArr = GetPotholes(start_ret_val);

                    MessageBox.Show("Analysis completed");

                    //bar.Dispatcher.Invoke(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Normal,
                      //                  new Action( delegate() { bar.Value = 0; } ));
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Analysis returned with error code : " + start_ret_val); //@todo Add some interpretation here
                }

                Console.WriteLine("Got this far5");
            }                
        }
```

}

The C++ function starts here:

```
cv::Mat RunClassifier(cv::Mat& frame, cv::Mat& mask, std::vector<CvANN_MLP*>& anns, std::vector<int>& criteria,std::vector<float>& thresholds, Mat& final_certainty)
{
    //instantiate certainty matrix
    std::vector<Mat> indiv_certs;
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < anns.size(); i++)
        indiv_certs.push_back(Mat::zeros(frame.size(), CV_32FC1) );
    Mat certainty = Mat::zeros(frame.size(), CV_32FC1);
    final_certainty = Mat::zeros(frame.size(), CV_32FC1);

    Mat final_image = frame.clone();
    Mat* individual_masks = new Mat[anns.size()]();
    for (unsigned int iter = 0; iter < anns.size();iter++)
    {
        individual_masks[iter] = Mat::zeros(frame.rows,frame.cols,CV_32F);
    }
    Mat final_mask = Mat::zeros(frame.rows,frame.cols,CV_32F);

    //Convert the image to HSV colorspace (You could probably save a bit more if you converted and normalised the frame to 32F beforehand
    // and not individually for each channel.
    Mat hsv;
    std::vector<Mat> hsv_channels;
    cvtColor(frame, hsv, CV_BGR2HSV);
    split(hsv, hsv_channels);

    Mat hue, value, saturation;
    hsv_channels.at(HUE).convertTo(hue, CV_32F);
    hue /= HUE_MAX;
    hue = 1- hue;   
    hsv_channels.at(SATURATION).convertTo(saturation, CV_32F);
    Mat sat_pure = saturation.clone();
    saturation /= SATURATION_MAX;
    hsv_channels.at(VALUE).convertTo(value, CV_32F);
    value /= VALUE_MAX;

    //loop through the anns 
    //Declare multithreading variables
    PCERT_DATA pCert_Array[3];
    DWORD dwThreadIdArray[3];
    HANDLE hThreadArray[3];

    for (unsigned int ann_iter = 0; ann_iter < anns.size(); ann_iter++)
    {
        //allocate memory for thread data
        pCert_Array[ann_iter] = (PCERT_DATA) HeapAlloc(GetProcessHeap(), HEAP_ZERO_MEMORY, sizeof(CERT_DATA) );

        bool fft_flag = FALSE;
        //Convert the image block according to the ann
        switch (criteria.at(ann_iter))
        {
            case HUE:
            {
                pCert_Array[ann_iter]->converted_frame = &hue;
                break;
            }
            case SATURATION:
            {
                pCert_Array[ann_iter]->converted_frame = &saturation;
                break;
            }
            case VALUE:
            {
                pCert_Array[ann_iter]->converted_frame = &value;;
                break;
            }
            case FREQUENCY:
            {
                pCert_Array[ann_iter]->converted_frame = &sat_pure;
                fft_flag = TRUE;
                break;
            }
            default:
            {
                return Mat();
            }
        }


        //assign data to memory
        pCert_Array[ann_iter]->ann = anns.at(ann_iter);
        pCert_Array[ann_iter]->certainty = &(indiv_certs[ann_iter]);

        pCert_Array[ann_iter]->mask = &mask;
        pCert_Array[ann_iter]->fft_flag = fft_flag;
        pCert_Array[ann_iter]->individual_mask =  &(individual_masks[ann_iter]);
        pCert_Array[ann_iter]->threshold = thresholds.at(ann_iter);

        //call CalculateCertainty
        hThreadArray[ann_iter] = CreateThread( 
            NULL,                   // default security attributes
            0,                      // use default stack size  
            ComputeCertainty,       // thread function name
            pCert_Array[ann_iter],          // argument to thread function 
            0,                      // use default creation flags 
            &dwThreadIdArray[ann_iter]);   // returns the thread identifier         
    }

    //wait for all the threads to stop computing
    WaitForMultipleObjects(anns.size(), hThreadArray, TRUE, INFINITE);

    //summing operation of certanties
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < anns.size(); i++)
        certainty += indiv_certs[i];

    //AND all the various ANN outputs
    Mat temp = Mat::zeros(individual_masks[0].size(), individual_masks[0].type() );
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < anns.size(); i++)
        temp += individual_masks[i];

    Mat temp_binary_mask = (temp == anns.size());
    temp = Mat::ones(individual_masks[0].size(), individual_masks[0].type() );
    temp.copyTo(final_mask, temp_binary_mask);

    cv::multiply(final_mask, certainty, final_certainty, 1.0/anns.size() );

    delete individual_masks;

    //deallocate threading memory used
    for(unsigned int i=0; i<anns.size(); i++)
    {
        CloseHandle(hThreadArray[i]);
        if(pCert_Array[i] != NULL)
        {
            HeapFree(GetProcessHeap(), 0, pCert_Array[i]);
            pCert_Array[i] = NULL;    // Ensure address is not reused.
        }
    }

    return final_mask;
}
```

Comment: If you're mixing Debug and Release DLLs or EXE's, you can get this "error" (in which case, it's not an error but a difference in behaviour caused by different memory allocators).

Comment: @crashmstr I will edit the post and add the c#. I checked and Im not mixing DLLs or EXE files

Comment: please use a vector for individual_masks in the c++ code. avoid pointers to cv::Mat

Answer (score 3):

- Have you tried to use memory leak detection tools, such as [Visual Leak Detector](https://vld.codeplex.com/)?
- In below code,

  `Mat* individual_masks = new Mat[anns.size()]();`

  should be deleted by using `operator delete[]`, so `delete[] individual_masks;`
- Also, there should be array boundary check, regardless of memory leak.

  ```
  for (unsigned int ann_iter = 0; ann_iter < anns.size(); ann_iter++) 
  { 
      //allocate memory for thread data 
      pCert_Array[ann_iter] = (PCERT_DATA) HeapAlloc(GetProcessHeap(), HEAP_ZERO_MEMORY, sizeof(CERT_DATA) );
  ```

  `anns` is input parameter, so it's size will be not fixed value, but `pCert_Array` is declared in `PCERT_DATA pCert_Array[3];`.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. We train  Neural Nets on three features so anns in our case will always be three but its not good programming practise. So even with how you say I should delete the Mat pointer object I still get the same problem, im trying to make VLD work still